# What is the performance impact of the touch command or its equivalent system call?

Tags: node.js, linux, performance, system-calls, benchmarking

In a custom-developed NodeJS web server (running on Linux) that can dynamically generate thumbnail images, I want to cache these thumbnails on the filesystem and keep track of when they are actually used. If they haven't been used for a certain period of time (say, one year), I'd consider them "orphans" and delete them.

To this end, I considered to `touch` them each time they're requested from a client, so that I can use the modification time to check when they were last used.

I assume this would incur a significant performance hit on the web server in high-load situations, as it is an "unnecessary" filesystem write, while, apart from logging, most requests will only consist of reads.

Has anyone performed any benchmarks on how big an impact this might have and if it's worthwhile?

Comment: We've had something like 50 years of optimising file system calls. Are you really sure a `touch` of all things would be a bottleneck? Besides, for decades now, file system writes are written to a buffer and the content of the buffer synced occasionally in order to prevent rapid changes, and just do fewer bigger ones. That's the reason why flash drives might lose data if you pull them unsafely - the buffer is not written yet, what you see in the file explorer is the data that *would be there* if it was written. So, I'm not sure why `touch` would have a performance impact.

Comment: That's also just concerning traditional drives. With SSDs you have even less of a direct access - they have their own internal controllers that optimise writes. And there are many, many setups that might have other considerations - if you have a RAID setup, if you use certain file systems with built-in redundancy, then writes might be slower *or even faster*.

Comment: As with all performance questions, benchmark it and see for yourself.

Comment: For *nix; a file is supposed to have 3 timestamps - creation, last modification, and last access.  To improve performance, most people disable "access time" for most file systems using mount options. Using `touch()` to convert "modification time" into "access time" would have a similar performance impact to not disabling "access time". You will probably be able to find information about the performance impact of enabling/disabling "access time" (and use it as an estimate of the performance impact of your `touch()` emulation); but anything you find will be system specific.

Comment: Note that you might be able to use this as an alternative option - e.g. if you had a small partition/file system dedicated to thumbnails, where "access time" is enabled for that small file system (and not any other file systems), then you'd achieve the same end result without the overhead of extra system calls (`touch()`). In that case, performance will still probably be dominated by disk IO (the writes) so it probably wouldn't make much difference (depending on how the OS does write buffering).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably not great, and probably worth avoiding updating *every* time you open a file.  That's the reason the `relatime` / `noatime` mount options were invented, to prevent the existing Unix access-time timestamp from being updated every time a file was opened.

Is your filesystem mounted with `relatime`?  That updates atime at most once per day, when the file is opened (even for reading).  The other mount option that's common on Linux is `noatime`: never update atime.

If you can't let the kernel do this for you without needing extra system calls, you might be better off making an `fstat` system call after opening the file and only touching it to update the mod time if the mod time is older than a day or week. (You're concerned about intervals of a year, so a week is fine.)  **i.e. manually implement the relatime logic, but for mod time.**

Frequently accessed files will not need updates (and you're still making a total of one system call for them, plus a date-compare).  Rarely accessed files will need another system call and a metadata write.  If most of the accesses in your access pattern are to a smallish set of files repeatedly, this should be excellent.

---

Possible reasons for not being able to use `atime` could include:

- The filesystem is mounted with noatime and it's not worth changing that
- The files sometimes get read by something other than your web server / CGI setup.  (e.g. a backup job that does more than compare size / timestamps)

---

Of course, the other option is to *not* update timestamps on use, and simply let a thumbnail be regenerated once a year after your weekly cron job deleted it.  That might be ok depending on your workload.

If you manually touch some of the "hottest" thumbnails so you stagger their deletion, instead of having a big load spike this time next year, you could be ok.  And/or have your deleter walk your filesystem very slowly, again so you don't have a big batch of frequently-needed thumbnails deleted at once.

You could come up with schemes like enabling mod-time updates in the week before the bi-annual cleanup, so thumbnails that should stay hot in cache get their modtimes updated.  But probably better to just fstat / check / update all the time since that shouldn't be too much extra load.

Comment: Contrary to these ridiculous stackoverflow rules, I'll say "Thanks" because that's what normal human beings do. Thanks for the great detailed answer! In the end, I checked the mount options and they already had "relatime", and I researched a bit on that and it's a very good compromise between accuracy and performance hit. One day granularity is more than enough, so I'm just going with checking atime.

Comment: @SevenSystems: Interesting to hear that you did already have relatime.  Don't forgot to "accept" the answer as well, with the checkbox under the vote arrows, if that solves your problem.